# Tinymce Laravel Integration Error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.4, tinymce-4

I am trying to integrate tinymce in one of my crud add/edit but getting an unusual error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4SM4.png)

My tinymce init code is as below

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: '#title, #thumbnail_title',
            height: 100,
            theme: 'modern',
            menubar: 'edit insert format tools',

            plugins: 'searchreplace autolink directionality image link media advlist textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern code',
            toolbar1: 'formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat code',
            image_advtab: true,
            image_dimensions: false,
            image_class_list: [
                {title: 'responsive', value: 'img-responsive'},
            ],
            content_css: [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth|Anton|Dancing+Script|Didact+Gothic|Fira+Sans+Condensed|Francois+One|Lato|Lobster|Lobster+Two|Muli|Open+Sans|Pacifico|Passion+One|Playfair+Display|Playfair+Display+SC|Quattrocento|Quattrocento+Sans|Sanchez|Shadows+Into+Light|Shadows+Into+Light+Two|Spectral+SC|Yrsa',

            ],
            font_formats : 'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats;Didact Gothic=Didact Gothic, sans-serif;Open Sans=Open Sans, sans-serif;Lato=Lato, sans-serif;Spectral SC=Spectral SC, serif;Playfair Display SC=Playfair Display SC, serif;Muli=Muli, sans-serif;Anton=Anton, sans-serif;Lobster=Lobster, cursive;Lobster Two=Lobster Two, cursive;Playfair Display=Playfair Display, serif;Pacifico=Pacifico, cursive;Shadows Into Light=Shadows Into Light, cursive;Shadows Into Light Two=Shadows Into Light Two, cursive;Dancing Script=Dancing Script, cursive;Francois One=Francois One, sans-serif;Passion One=Passion One, cursive;Sanchez=Sanchez, serif;Quattrocento Sans=Quattrocento Sans, sans-serif;Quattrocento=Quattrocento, serif;Amaranth=Amaranth, sans-serif;Fira Sans Condensed=Fira Sans Condensed, sans-serif;Yrsa=Yrsa, serif;',

            fontsize_formats: '8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px 42px 72px',
            protect: [
                /\<\/?(if|endif)\>/g,  // Protect <if> & </endif>
                /\<xsl\:[^>]+\>/g,  // Protect <xsl:...>
                /<\?php.*?\?>/g  // Protect php code
            ],
            forced_root_block: false,
            verify_html: true,
            branding:false,
            theme_advanced_fonts : ''
        });
```

It seems nice when I edit but when I shows html tags after saving the data and reloading the edit page.

Comment: Add more content to your question for better clearance...

Comment: may be its because you are using `varchar` in database instead `text` ?

Comment: yes that was the problem. I have found and fixed, thanks @user2486

Comment: Your welcome Manish bhai,  I was also faced this issue before